# Running multiple evaluation instances of SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, evaluation

I'm playing around with sql 2008 server. I have already installed an enterprise evaluation instance and i added another one. Installation runs fine, but i cannot connect to the second instance. Server is running for both instances.

Is that a restriction for the evaluation mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe multiple instances of the evaluation edition should work. Do you have the SQL Server Browser running and (if you are trying to connect from a different machine) its port, and the port in use by the second instance, open in your firewall settings? [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx) has a good reference of how to configure multiple instances for access beyond the firewall.

To confirm that the problem is/isn't the eval edition, add a named instance of SQL Express (you can remove it immediately after this test) - if the SQL Express instance is not connectible either than the eval-ness of the other invisible instance it not the problem.

Comment: SQLExpress instance works fine, SQLBrowser runs but the second instance get not listed when searching. FW is off.

Comment: That is working now. I was trying to call the default instance as "SERVER\MSSQLSERVER". If i use only "SERVER" it works.

Comment: Yeah,. Because MSSQLSERVER is the DEFAULT NAME, i.e. the DEFAULT INSTANCE ;)